# If statement checking for NSString equality using ==

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, string-comparison

I am making a server call in some Objective-c code. If it returns as a `@"yes"`, it will do an action. For some reason, the `// DO ACTION HERE` part is never reached.

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *returnStringResults = returnString;
NSString *yesText = @"yes";

if (returnStringResults == yesText) {
    testLabel.text = @"Success";
    // DO ACTION HERE
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ([returnStringResults isEqualToString:yesText]) {
    testLabel.text = @"Success";
    // DO ACTION HERE
}
```

Edit: As bbum pointed out, `NSString *returnStringResults = returnString;` does nothing.

So really, remove that line and use

```
if ([returnString isEqualToString:yesText]) {
    testLabel.text = @"Success";
    // DO ACTION HERE
}
```

Comment: Also `NSString *returnStringResults = returnString;` has no purpose.

Comment: Also, you kinda need square brackets when you do method calls. (I added them)

Comment: Thank Dave, I was so focused on the "isEqualToString:" part... My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing pointer addresses. The way this code works `yesText` and `returnStringResults` are pointers to different NSString instances, thus the pointers are not equal. You've to use NSString `isEqualToString` method to compare.