# How to compare self.title to a string in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, if-statement

What am I doing wrong in the below code? My if statement is missing something:

```
if ([self.title] = "Upcoming Events") {

} else {

}
```

Comment: Not to be mean, but I suggest you learn programming first.

Comment: i learn obj-c a few months ago and burnt myself out a little doing it, just picked it back up few days ago. lol, but yea, i need a bit more revision

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C If statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987770/objective-c-if-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct would be:

```
if( [self.title isEqualToString:@"Upcoming Events"] )
```

self.title is a pointer, you can only compare it to other pointers using == not their values.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to write like this:

```
if([self.title isEqualToString:@"Upcoming Events"])
{

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Upcoming Events"]) {
   NSLog(@"True");
} else {
 NSLog(@"False");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also .... in a if you should use "==" instead of "=". When there is "==" it is checking if they are equal while if there is "=" it gives the first one the value of the second.