# How to compare strings? (`==` returns wrong value)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, if-statement

I've got myself a piece of the iPhone SDK and been trying to make some simple apps. In this one, i want to compare the first character of `self.label.string` with the last one of `((UITextField *)sender).text`. I decided to name them `self.texty` and `self.input`, respectively.

I would expect this if statement returning `yes` to me under certain circumstances, however I can't seem to get that done.

(in my case, my `self.label.string` was equal to 'hello!', while my `self.input` ended in an 'h'.)

```
self.input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [((UITextField *)sender).text substringFromIndex:[((UITextField *)sender).text length]-1]];
self.texty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.label.string substringToIndex:1]];

if (self.input == self.texty) {
    return yes;
} else {
    return no;
}
```

Comment: It works correctly. `==` does not work as you expect. Use one of the NSString "compare" methods. This should be covered in a tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C If statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987770/objective-c-if-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String comparison is not done with `==`, but with one of the [comparison methods of NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

For example:

```
if ([self.input compare:self.texty] == NSOrderedSame) {
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ([self.input isEqualToString:texty]) {
    return yes;
} else {
    return no;
}
```

EDIT:

Or a better version as the commenters noted:

```
return [self.input isEqualToString:texty];
```

Comment: return [self.input isEqualToString:texty];

Comment: Good point... I was putting it in the context of his code sample, but the if statement is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're curious why the == operator doesn't work as expected, it's because you're actually comparing two scalar types (pointers to NSString objects) not the contents of the NSString objects themselves. As a result, it will return false unless the two compared NSStrings are actually the same instance in memory, regardless of the contents.

Comment: I actually WAS wondering. Thank you a whole bunch for making that clear!