# How to check what text is in a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare strings? (`==` returns wrong value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683353/how-to-compare-strings-returns-wrong-value)

I have the following code but nothing happens, why is this?:

```
if(Assignment1DueDate.text == @"0 days until due"){

        [Assignment1DueDate setText:@"Due tomorrow"];

        [maincelltext addObject:Assignment1.text];
        [subtitlecelltext removeObject:Assignment1DueDate.text];
        [subtitlecelltext addObject:Assignment1DueDate.text];

}
```

P.S. Assignment1DueDate is the UILabel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if([Assignment1DueDate.text isEqualToString:@"0 days until due"]){

 // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use isEqualToString method for comparing 2 strings. The strings can not be compared using '==' operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([Assignment1DueDate.text isEqualToString :@"0 days until due"])
{
}
```

if you are comparing the strings then you have to use the isEqualToString.If you are comparing the two objects the you have to use the isEqual function

Answer (score 0):

The code below is used for Case_Insensitive comparison of two strings.

```
 UILabel *labl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 80)];
 labl.text = @"my Label";
 [self.view addSubview:labl];


 if ([ labl.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"MY LABel"]==NSOrderedSame) 
 {
     // Code to be executed if Assignment1DueDate is equal to the entered String.
     NSLog(@"Label and String are Same");
 }
 else
 {
     // Code to be executed if Assignment1DueDate is Not equal to the entered String.
     NSLog(@"Label and String are Not Same");
 }
```

Above code returns "Label and String are Same".
This code works fine and i have tested it. Hope it would help you.

Comment: I like the idea for this answer but I get this error: http://pastie.org/2794225 - what has gone wrong? :S

Comment: Hi reddexuk you must first take a label and set text to it. And after that compare it with the string.