# Compare strings in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302985/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-objective-c)
>   [Objective-C If statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987770/objective-c-if-statement)

When I try to compare strings in Objective-C using the == factor I am not getting any result. What I am doing is having an XML document and then retrieving the value "day" and then comparing those. But as I said nothing happens.

XML Code:

```
<dagensretlist>
<dagensret>
<day>mandag</day>
<date>Mandag 2. juli</date>
<name>Kylling fillet med rosti og salat</name>
<description>Den sprodeste kyllingfillet med Antons piksved</description>
</dagensret>

<dagensret>
    <day>tirsdag</day>
<date>Tirsdag 3. juli</date>
<name>Kylling fillet med rosti og salat</name>
<description>Den sprodeste kyllingfillet med Antons piksved</description>
</dagensret>

<dagensret>
    <day>onsdag</day>
<date>Onsdag 4. juli</date>
<name>Kylling fillet med rosti og salat</name>
<description>Den sprodeste kyllingfillet med Antons piksved</description>
</dagensret>

<dagensret>
<day>torsdag</day>
    <date>Torsdag 5. juli</date>
<name>Kylling fillet med rosti og salat</name>
<description>Den sprodeste kyllingfillet med Antons piksved</description>
</dagensret>

<dagensret>
    <day>fredag</day>
<date>Fredag 6. juli</date>
<name>Kylling fillet med rosti og salat</name>
<description>Den sprodeste kyllingfillet med Antons piksved</description>
</dagensret>
</dagensretlist>
```

The code itself:

```
- (void)getCurrencyList {
    NSArray *currencyList = [self getAllItems:@"//dagensret" fileName:@"dagensret.xml"];
    int numberOfCurrencies = [currencyList count];
    
    NSString *name, *date, *description, *day;
    if (numberOfCurrencies > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCurrencies; i++) {
            
            name            = [[currencyList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
            day             = [[currencyList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"day"];
            date            = [[currencyList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
            description     = [[currencyList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
            
            if(day==@"1"){
                NSLog(@"day: %@, date: %@, name: %@, description: %@", day, date, name, description);
                NSLog(@"1");
            }
            if(day==@"tirsdag"){
                NSLog(@"day: %@, date: %@, name: %@, description: %@", day, date, name, description); 
            }
            if(day==@"onsdag"){
                NSLog(@"day: %@, date: %@, name: %@, description: %@", day, date, name, description); 
            } 
            if(day==@"torsdag"){
                NSLog(@"day: %@, date: %@, name: %@, description: %@", day, date, name, description); 
            } 
            if(day==@"fredag"){
                NSLog(@"day: %@, date: %@, name: %@, description: %@", day, date, name, description); 
            }             
            
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a wrong way to compare strings to a variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Please make sure your question doesn't depend on pastebins - if you have only outside links to your code, your question becomes useless as soon as these links die; and they do die.

Comment: I think Links are not working

Comment: `if ([day isEqualToString:@"tirsdag"])` etc

Comment: This question has been asked a million times. Please search before asking it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use  `isEqualToString` from NSString class to compare strings

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407803-isequaltostring)

Comment: Yep, the two strings will never be equivalent since, at minimum, one is a constant and one is a variable.

Comment: I guess that's the problem when coming from PHP.... Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

use the following if condition...

```
if([day isEqualToString:@"1"]){
   // your code
}...
```

use all if like this..

may this will help you..